# How to remove the resizig handlers around an image in IE with javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, resize, image-resizing, resizable

I have a small editor in my web site and I can add an image on it. I can resize the images using a jQuery plugin (Resizable). For this reason I had to disable the resizing borders around the image. In Firefix I did it using this:

```
 execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, false);
```

and it worked fine. How can I do something similar for IE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't, I'm afraid. The only way to include a non-resizable image in an editable element in IE is to set it as the background image of an element and ensure that element does not [have layout](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout).

Comment: Yes I know that there is a problem with the layout. I just hoped to find another solution. I will try this anyway. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same effect in IE11, you can use this code (javascript):

```
function controlselectHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
document.body.addEventListener('mscontrolselect', controlselectHandler);
```

This removes the handles and resizing functionality. The cursor still changes to a resize cursor on hover, but this should be solveable with css.

I am not sure whether this will work in previous version of IE.